# Switch error:: cannot appear in a constant-expression

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, switch-statement

this is a strange one...

I am playing with some decompression algo. Instead of going through the `char buffer[]` and looping until a stop-bit in  `buffer[i]` is found, I am trying use some bit-mask techniques but with chars.

I have the following example:

```
// In a *.h file  
const char ch = '\x81';  
// To avoid Endianess  
union CharUInt  
{  
    char sz[4];  
    unsigned int u;  
};  
// Legal because char[] is declared before uint32 in the union  
const CharUInt Mask1 = {'\x81', '\x0', '\x0', '\x81'};  
const CharUInt Mask2 = {'\x0', '\x81', '\x81', '\x0'};  
// Proxy / Auxillary uint32 as usimg Mask2.u in the switch blocked produced the same errors  
const unsigned int uMask1 = Mask1.u;  
const unsigned int uMask2 = Mask2.u;  
const unsigned int uMask_ = (uMask1 & uMask2);  
// buf is always long enough  
bool Foo(char buf[])  
{  
    const CharUInt Type = {buf[0], buf[1], buf[2], buf[3]};  
    unsigned int uType = (Type.u & uMask_);  
    switch(uType)  
    {  
    case uMask1:  
        // do stuff  
    case uMask2:    
        // do more stuff  
        return true;  
        break;  
    default:  
        // do different stuff  
        return false;  
        break;  
    }  
};
```

Without considering the syntax of the `union` stuff (the actual code compiles run fine for that) and without considering whether the function-return for `Foo` is pretty, I get
`'uMask1' cannot appear in a constant-expression`
and if the unions themselves are used, I get
`'Mask1' cannot appear in a constant-expression`
`'.' cannot appear in a constant-expression`
and of course the errors also apply for uMask2 and Mask2.u

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Was the colon after the union declaration intended?

Comment: Your error points out the reason. uMask1 should be replace by the constant data you need to check against, not uMask1 .

Answer (score 6):

The confusion comes from the fact that const and const are two.

The case's in the switch statement need 'constant expressions'.  Or in other words: expressions that can be 'calculated' by the compiler, at compile-time.
This could be a hard-coded number (like 42), or something that has been defined before as a number (using #define).

Const is also used by the compiler with the meaning "once this variable has a value, it won't change anymore".  E.g. in the following code:

```
void myFunction (const int value)
{
...
}
```

value will be const.  I will not be able to change the value of const, but this does not make it a 'constant expression' for the compiler.

In your case, uMask1 is const (can't change it anymore) but not a constant expression.

Comment: But why can't the compiler calculate the value of `uMask1` and `uMask2` at compile time? It has all information it would need to do that.

Comment: Yes, theoretically it could do that, but compilers don't have to do that.  That's why C++11 added the constexpr keyword.  It tells the compiler that it should evaluate the expression at compile time rather than run time.  Although I tried it in your case and it doesn't seem to help :-(

Answer (score 1):

`case` condition expression must be of integral type, or convertible to integral type, and must be const.

### 6.4.2 [stmt.switch]

> The condition shall be of integral
>   type, enumeration type, or of a class
>   type for which a single conversion
>   function to integral or enumeration
>   type exists (12.3). If the condition
>   is of class type, the condition is
>   converted by calling that conversion
>   function, and the result of the
>   conversion is used in place of the
>   original condition for the remainder
>   of this section. Integral promotions
>   are performed. Any statement within
>   the switch statement can be labeled
>   with one or more case labels as
>   follows:
>
> case constant-expression :
>
> where the constant-expression shall be
>   an integral constant-expression. The
>   integral constant-expression (5.19) is
>   implicitly converted to the promoted
>   type of the switch condition. No two
>   of the case constants in the same
>   switch shall have the same value after
>   conversion to the promoted type of the
>   switch condition.

Your expression isn't a constant expression, even though the variable itself is `const`, so you can't switch on it.  You'll need to use an `if`.

You have another problem though:

You create a `union`,

```
union CharUInt  
{  
    char sz[4];  
    unsigned int u;  
};
```

...then you initialize the `sz` member of that union,

```
static const CharUInt Mask1 = {'\x81', '\x0', '\x0', '\x81'};
```

...and then you access the `u` member of that union.

```
static const unsigned int uMask1 = Mask1.u;
```

This evokes undefined behavior according to the standard.  In the language of the Standard, 2 members of a union can't be active at one time.  Meaning you can't treat a union like a caster.

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for the answer. Is there a hack around this apart from doing ifdef's for all possible and interesting endianess...? Also, what do you mean that '2 members of a union can't be active at one time'? in the code it's actually <code>typedef struct _tagType{ union {...}; } TypeT;</code>